# İnput number кастомизация стрелкок

Tags: html, css

Хочу сделать стрелки верх и вниз красными без фона.И тольк очерез css без каких либо картинок.

Почему отображается только верхняя стрелка?
Помогите исправить это за ранее спасибо.

```css
input[type=number] {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 0 8px;
}
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
  opacity:1;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
    width:8px;
    color: #333;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
}


input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button { 
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
  display:block;
 border-left: 8px solid transparent;
 border-right: 8px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 8px solid red;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button
{
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-left: 5px solid transparent;
 border-right: 5px solid transparent;
 border-top: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" value="0" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант

```css
input[type=number] {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0 8px;
}
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  width: 8px;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;  
}

.field-number{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.field-number:before,
.field-number:after{
  content: ''; 
  position: absolute; right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  display: block;
  border-style: solid;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.field-number:before{  
  top: 7px; 
  border-width: 0 8px 8px 8px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #f00 transparent;
}
.field-number:after{  
  bottom: 7px;  
  border-width: 8px 8px 0 8px;
  border-color: #f00 transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="field-number">
  <input type="number" value="0">
</div>
```